# Get index of current playing/paused song in playlist [Windows Media Player Library]

Tags: c#, windows-media-player, axwindowsmediaplayer

Here is my media player playlist code setup, working with the windows media player library.

Right now what I'm doing is creating the media player and giving it a playlist.

```
WindowsMediaPlayer wmPlayer = new WindowsMediaPlayer();
wmPlayer.PlayStateChange += Player_PlayStateChange;
IWMPPlaylist playlist = wmPlayer.playlistCollection.newPlaylist("All");
wmPlayer.currentPlaylist = playlist;
```

I then add songs to the playlist

```
IWMPMedia media = _wmPlayer.newMedia(path); //path to mp3 is given via method parameter
wmPlayer.currentPlaylist.appendItem(media);
```

This allows me to easily execute basic music player controls and I don't need to manually go to the next/previous song.

```
wmPlayer.controls.play();
wmPlayer.controls.pause();
wmPlayer.controls.next();
wmPlayer.controls.previous();
```

What I would like to do is get the index of the current media that is playing/paused in the playlist (`wmPlayer.currentPlaylist`). Is that possible?

I know that you can get a song at a specific index via `wmPlayer.currentPlaylist.Item[index];`, but I cannot find out how to get the index of the current song.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

May the following code help you.

```
        int index;
        for (int i = 0; i < playlist.count - 1; i++)
        {
            if (wmPlayer.currentMedia.isIdentical[playlist.Item[i]])
            {
                index = i;
                break;
            }
        }
```